# serving polymer bundles conditionally

Tags: polymer-2.x, serving

What are the options for service polymer es6-bundle,es5-bundle and unbundled versions conditionally ?

preferred option would be nginx if that's possible, so basically how to detect HTTP2 and if there's good regex for user agent to detect es6

Answer (score 2):

i have found next solution:

**On backend** you should define map like so:

```
map $cookie_build $assets_suffix {
    ""    "";
    "no"             "";
    "es6-bundled"    "build/es6-bundled/";
    "es6-unbundled"  "build/es6-unbundled/";
    "es5-bundled"    "build/es5-bundled/";
}
```

and polymer's assets location define something like this

```
location /polymer-app/ {
    alias /app/public/frontend/$assets_suffix;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /polymer-app/index.html;
}
```

so, by default, nginx serves development build, and when there is defined cookie for build version it serves appropriate build of application.

**On clientside**

You should detect browser capabilities for example using this gist  https://gist.github.com/DaBs/89ccc2ffd1d435efdacff05248514f38 or by any other feature-detect-* library
Then you should set corresponding cookie and call `window.location.reload(true)`.

In my case, i have a separate landing page based on cms, so browser detection processed on it and when user hits application, corresponding cookie is already set.

Comment: There is one more solution based on user-agent matching https://gitlab.techcultivation.org/sangha/sangha-frontend/issues/6

Comment: that's great, although I ended up using https://github.com/Polymer/prpl-server-node with nginx as reverse proxy